# Openssl Certificate Chain

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, x509, pki

Executed the command:

```
openssl s_client  -connect (redacted):443
```

and I get the output

```
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.(redacted)
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = *.(redacted)
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
---
```

What does the error "unable to get local issuer certificate" mean? From the above I can see that the full chain is there, and that the root CA "DST Root CA X3" signed the "R3" cert. So surely that R3 cert does not need to be explicitly trusted? Is this good enough?
Is this cause for concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate

The trust chain from the leaf (server certificate) via the intermediate chain certificates (R3) must end in a **locally trusted** root CA (DST Root CA X3). Obviously this root CA is not locally trusted in the CA store used by your openssl setup (or maybe you have explicitly used `-CApath` or `-CAfile`).

Comment: Thanks. This is very unexpected for me as it is a very common root CA, pretty much universally trusted. I was initially confused about the seemingly conflicting information here with the "verify return:1" and the "verify error"

Comment: @user98651: I guess the problem is the setup of your system or your openssl. For me this CA is in the default trust store used by OpenSSL in Ubuntu 20.04 and it verifies without problems. Note that for example on Windows OpenSSL will not use the system trust store but requires its own - and if this is not properly setup it will fail like in your question